# Views Grouped filter returns empty set

Tags: views

I am using Drupal 7 and Views 7.x-3.7.

In a view I have an exposed filter "gender".

If I select the filter type as 'single', it works fine. But I want radio buttons rather than dropdown so I select 'grouped filter' option.

[image]

Then the filter renders as I like.

[image]

But it always returns an empty result set.

There must be a setting that I am missing. Can you please point me to it?

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to concentrate on your question because your screenprints aren't using english. Can you change that.

Comment: @Marcel Replaced the images

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could not find a way to make the grouped filter work for me. The solution I found was to use the [Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module. It is quite easy to configure. It worked smoothly for me.